# Картинки сразу "уходят" в угол при смене разрешения

Tags: шаблоны, css

Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему так происходит с отображением картинок мой сайт  http://emelinna.com/ , то есть при нажатии Ctrl+ Ctrl- или смене расширения монитора картинки сразу "уходят" в левый верхний угол, а вот на этом  http://www.elenavasichkina.com/album/9/  и при смене разрешения монитора и при нажатии Ctrl+ Ctrl-  такого резкого "ухода" картинок не происходит. Буду признателен в помощи.

Comment: Код предоставьте.

Comment: Это же движок вордпресс.
Можно по ссылке посмотреть через Firebug

Comment: Если чужой сайт на wordpress работает правильно, а ваш нет, проблема в вашем коде. Если вам лень найти отличие между вашим кодом и чужим, почему вы думаете, что нам будет не лень? (Кстати, <http://sscce.org/>.)